# collection on value as table in the from

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to do a join in a big list of static value, from a non-sql origin.
I could use a temp table, but, 
years ago, I remember use an alternative to temp table: I specified a list of value in select, whiche was automatically converted into a table; without need of temp table or something.

something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table ('A','B','C') T1
```

I search the exact syntaxe of this, any idea?

Comment: select 'A' as A,'B','C'

Comment: How are you receving the list of values - as a single CSV string?

Comment: found the solution in an other stack... but it's not the solution that have been selected as the "best solution" 

select * from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'));

Comment: Do you want A, B and C as columns in one row, or as separate rows?

Comment: @jarlh separate rows please

Answer (score 0):

select * from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'));